# technicolor router can't access localhost from public ip

Tags: router, remote-access, webserver, network-adapter, localhost

My provider gave me a new router (which sucks compared to the one I had; 2wire), it's Technicolor TG582n software version 10.2.0.B.

I looked around for remote management in the router administration but there is not such a thing. There is remote assistance but it says it is disabled.

I think it's pretty bad that ANYONE can see the router login page (just type my IP and there it is) and I'm sure it would be easy to brute force the login page.

I have also tried from another network, and I still get the login page.

How can I disable the public login page of my router?

Comment: Can you not ask your provider to swap out the device for something more useful?

Comment: on the phone with them. I hope I get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict web login permissions to specific subnets

```
service system ipadd name=HTTP ip=<subnet>/<mask>
```

for example

```
service system ipadd name=HTTP ip=192.168.1.0/24
```

you can confirm this with

```
service system list name=HTTP expand=enabled
```

HTTPS can also be managed replacing the keyword HTTP with HTTPs in the above examples, for Telnet replace it with TELNET...

You can also port forward ports 23 and 80...

Comment: Andrews and Arnold have a reasonably comprehensive page http://wiki.aa.org.uk/index.php/TG582N

Comment: is that a firewall? I'm using windows and for my solution I bought a cisco modem. Technicolor is downright horrible.